# Volume blinking up and down rapidly on Gnome Shell

Tags: sound, gnome, alsa

I've been having this problem where the volume goes up and down extremely fast and it makes the audio of videos sound like they're skipping. Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: In the Sound Preferences, on the output tab the Connecter: is switching from Analog Output to Analog Headphones, this is what is probably changing the volume.

Answer (score 4):

> > I've fixed the issue, no problem now, you have to disable the auto-mute option in alsamixer.

*as you said in an edit to your post*